# ASUS PC Fan issue

Tags: fan, desktop-computer

I have an ASUS Desktop PC with intel CORE i7. I tried turning it on and here's what happens.

After 5 seconds of turning it on (approximate) it raises the fan on the middle to the max level. It keeps a huge noise and when I checked the CPU temperature on BIOS it showed that the CPU temperature is 88°C. CPU RPM is constantly on 4500~. 
 The computer shuts itself down after couple of minutes of use, after that it will only be powered on for 2-3 seconds and then will shut itself down again, until you wait some while it lets you run the computer for a while, the fan problem still exists tho :/

If anyone has countered the same problem or knows a solution, I would love to hear how to fix it! Maybe it's a problem in the BIOS settings? Who knows. Anyways, thanks in advance.

Here are few updated pictures of my PC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a hardware failure.  88°C is extremely hot for any generation of a i7.

Comment: Note that BIOS load and early boot are rather hot periods for a CPU/Mobo, because advanced power management has not yet been loaded, but 88C is well beyond bounds. If you trust that its actually spinning at 4500RPM, then its likely that the heatsink is not sufficiently contacting the CPU. I'd recommend that you remove and remount the heatsink, using the right amount of thermal paste. Also confirm that the heatsink "fins" are not dusty, and that your fans are arranged for a clean and unambigious air flow pattern (in the front and side, out the top and back.) bind up any cables restricting air.

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for the reply! I'm now looking at my PC from the inside, I'll provide a picture or two to my post in case you'll spot something that's wrong.

Comment: @FrankThomas When I was on BIOS settings, I think I saw "CHA_FAN = N /A" or something similar, the middle fan has a black & blue & red cable which has white end which connects to the motherboard port "CHA_FAN". Does this mean that the cable is violated or not intact somehow?

Comment: pics look good. so get some thermal paste, and remove and remount the heatsink. if you've never done it before, study up on the process first.

Comment: your motherboard has multiple fan headers (pin connectors) and if you have fewer fans than your motherboard provides headers, some of the headers will report NA (just meaning nothing is plugged into me). Not having a chasis fan is a big problem, but it takes time for the chasis to heat up enough to affect other components temperatures, so if you shut down for an hour, and boot up, and immediately experience very high temps, then the chasis cooling is not the issue. Also note, there is nothing in your BOIS that will address the issue you have reported unless you overclock.

Comment: @FrankThomas I will! :) Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @FrankThomas Didn't need to change thermal paste. The heatsink was not properly attached to the CPU, I attached it and the computer is running now with silent noise and properly :) You can add it as an answer so I can mark it as an proper solution. Thanks a lot!